# Proof: Tree with vertices

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, proof-verification

Prove: If G is a tree than vertices of G can be numbered v1,v2....,vn in such a way that
$(\forall i>1)|{vk:vkvi \in E(G)\land}k<i|=1$

So my idea is to do it by PHP (Pigeonhole principle):

v is number of vertices

e- number of edges

e=v-1 by definition.

so |e|<|v| than by PHP  it's true

Is it a good idea?

Comment: What is "PHP" in this context? Is your tree oriented or non-oriented?

Comment: @HenningMakholm I mean Pigeonhole principle

Comment: Your idea doesn't sound convincing. If all you use is that $e=v-1$, then it would seem that your argument would work just as well for a graph consisting of a triangle and an isolated vertex -- but that graph doesn't have the property you're trying to prove!

Comment: so is there any way to do it by PHP? all I need to use some other proof?

Comment: Pick up the tree by any vertex and let it dangle. Number the vertices starting at the top, making arbitrary choices for vertices the same distance from the top.

Comment: can you write it in proof form? I don't know how to write this as math proof.